# Request a paper by Fred Cohen

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I am looking for the following paper by Cohen, F. R.:

> On combinatorial group theory in homotopy. Homotopy theory and its
>   applications (Cocoyoc, 1993), 57–63,  Contemp. Math., 188, Amer. Math.
>   Soc., Providence, RI, 1995.

Many thanks in advance for finding the paper for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can find here.](http://www.ams.org/books/conm/188/conm188.pdf)

In case if the link does not work, you can give your e-mail id. I will send you via e-mail.